# Best way to start a backbone.js app with multiple views and routes

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have started to use/learn backbone.js and come across something i don't quite understand.

If i have a page that on load should load a couple of items on every page, like a menu. Most of the examples i see fetches the collections, and renders the view in the router. But then it's locked to that route.

What is the best way to load some views for every page if it's not already loaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use the following pattern:

```
var App = { // a 'namespace' to hold references to my App's variables to avoid globals
    UI : {}  // references to UI components go here
}

// initialize stuff once the DOM is ready.
$(function(){
    App.UI.menu = App.UI.menu || new MenuView({ el : '#menu' }); // the || is in case it's been defined elsewhere. Just me being cautious;
    App.UI.footer = App.UI.footer || new FooterView({ el : '#footer' });
    App.router = App.router || new Router();
    Backbone.history.start()
});
```

The above requires that `MenuView` and `FooterView` call their `render` methods when initialized.  You need to have elements with `id="menu"` and `id="footer"` in your document as well.

```
var MenuView = Backbone.View.extend({
     initiaize : function(){
        this.render();
     },
     render : function(){
        // you'd probably use a template and iterate over an array of links.
        this.$el.html('<ul><li><a href="#">Menu item 1</a></li><li><a href="#">Menu item 2</a></li></ul>');
     }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for a good example, it helped me see things in a different way :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this small solution.

```
view = new BackboneView({ collection: yourCollection});
 $("body").append(view.render().el);
```

Add This in your Backbone View

```
 render: function() {
     $(this.el).html(this.headerTemplate);
     return this;
    }
```

Comment: So, render the view in a document.ready() or something? and then call backbone.history.start()?

Comment: I think you will write your backbone code under this. $(function() {
     // Handler for .ready() called.
    });This will equivalent to calling body onload.

Answer (score 1):

I guess, firstly, it is better to write  backbone.history.start(), after then you can hand each `url` changes. When you call `navigate`  router work, but there are two way to call navigate (may be you know about it)

```
  1 -> yourRouterName.navigate("newUrl") : //it doesn't use router, it only added newUrl to `baseUrl`
  2 -> yourRouterName.navigate("newUrl", true) : //it added newUrl to `baseUrl`, router works now.
```

The two way useful, but **you should know how to use it**